# 2sxc - Export this entire App - error

Tags: 2sxc

I installed clean:
dnn 9.1.1.
2sxc 9.14.0.

When I try to use : Export this entire App
for any app I get error in dnn admin log,
and nothing happend in UI

```
AbsoluteURL:/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/app-sys/ImportExport/ExportApp
DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID:f63dba3f-993e-495e-a0cb-55aa49d4f1ba
AssemblyVersion:
PortalId:-1
UserId:-1
TabId:-1
RawUrl:
Referrer:
UserAgent:
ExceptionHash:iw0UpCgoACvAXA7m77KV5aM70ck=
Message:Could not find a part of the path 'C:\root_www_folder\desktopmodules\tosic_sexycontent\SexyContent\ImportExport\Instructions'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This folder is missing in fresh install:

```
DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\ImportExport\Instructions
```

Create it manualy and export started to work.

Comment: The bug is fixed in last build